# Dynamic SQL in SSRS giving in error in converting the parameter to datetime

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I am trying to run this sp in ssrs but it is giving me the following error -

Failure to convert the parameter value from String to Datetime.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. It is a dynamic SQL. I know the error is in the date conversion where the date parameter is converted. The four parameters are - 
@dtAdjustedStart,@dtAdjustedEnd,@dtAdjustedStartLY,@dtAdjustedEndLY. Can anyone please help me on this -----

```
ALTER PROC SSRS_Specials_Performance_Report(@DB varchar(30),@cOperators  varchar(50),@dtAdjustedStart DATETIME,@dtAdjustedEnd DATETIME, @dtAdjustedStartLY   DATETIME,@dtAdjustedEndLY DATETIME,@cSalespoints 
varchar(30),@vcRankingColumn varchar(30), @vcRankingDirection varchar(30))

  AS 

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)




IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#transact_ty') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #transact_ty;
CREATE TABLE #transact_ty
(
special    CHAR(10),
quantity   INT,
admissions INT,
pr_ctr_1   INT,
pcsplit_1  MONEY,
pr_ctr_2   INT,
pcsplit_2  MONEY,
pr_ctr_3   INT,
pcsplit_3  MONEY,
pr_ctr_4   INT,
pcsplit_4  MONEY,
pr_ctr_5   INT,
pcsplit_5  MONEY,
pr_ctr_6   INT,
pcsplit_6  MONEY
);


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#transact_ly') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #transact_ly;
CREATE TABLE #transact_ly
(
special    CHAR(10),
quantity   INT,
admissions INT,
pr_ctr_1   INT,
pcsplit_1  MONEY,
pr_ctr_2   INT,
pcsplit_2  MONEY,
pr_ctr_3   INT,
pcsplit_3  MONEY,
pr_ctr_4   INT,
pcsplit_4  MONEY,
pr_ctr_5   INT,
pcsplit_5  MONEY,
pr_ctr_6   INT,
pcsplit_6  MONEY
)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ReportOutput') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #ReportOutput;
CREATE TABLE #ReportOutput
(
 Special            CHAR(10),
 SpecialDescription VARCHAR(25),
 SpecialAdmitsTY    INT,
 SpecialRevenueTY   MONEY,
 SpecialPctOfTotal  NUMERIC(12,4),
 SpecialRevenueLY   MONEY,
 ProfitCenter       VARCHAR(25),
 RevenueCenter      VARCHAR(25),
 AdmissionsTY       INT,
 RevenueTY          MONEY,
 TotalRevenueTY     MONEY,
 AdmissionsLY       INT,
 RevenueLY          MONEY,
 TotalRevenueLY     MONEY,
 AdmissionsVariance INT,
 RevenueVariance    MONEY
 );

 SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #transact_ty
 SELECT t.special,
   t.quantity,
   t.admissions,
   t.pr_ctr_1,
   t.pcsplit_1,
   t.pr_ctr_2,
   t.pcsplit_2,
   t.pr_ctr_3,
   t.pcsplit_3,
   t.pr_ctr_4,
   t.pcsplit_4,
   t.pr_ctr_5,
   t.pcsplit_5,
   t.pr_ctr_6,
   t.pcsplit_6
   FROM ' + @DB + '.dbo.transact t
    WHERE t.date_time BETWEEN CAST(''' + CONVERT(varchar,@dtAdjustedStart,120) + '''    AS DATE) AND CAST('''+ CONVERT(varchar,@dtAdjustedEnd,120) + ''' AS DATE) 
   AND t.operator IN ('''+ @cOperators + ''')
   AND t.salespoint IN (''' + @cSalespoints + ''')'

   EXEC(@SQL)

  SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #transact_ly
  SELECT t.special,
   t.quantity,
   t.admissions,
   t.pr_ctr_1,
   t.pcsplit_1,
   t.pr_ctr_2,
   t.pcsplit_2,
   t.pr_ctr_3,
   t.pcsplit_3,
   t.pr_ctr_4,
   t.pcsplit_4,
   t.pr_ctr_5,
   t.pcsplit_5,
   t.pr_ctr_6,
   t.pcsplit_6
   FROM ' + @DB + '.dbo.transact t
   WHERE t.date_time BETWEEN CAST('''+ CONVERT(varchar,@dtAdjustedStartLY,120) + ''' AS DATE) AND CAST(''' + CONVERT(varchar,@dtAdjustedEndLY,120)+ ''' AS DATE)
   AND t.operator IN (''' + @cOperators + ''')
   AND t.salespoint IN (''' + @cSalespoints + ''')'


  EXEC(@SQL)
```

Comment: if you PRINT @SQL before you execute it, does that give you any clues?   Can you post the result of a PRINT that gives the error?

Comment: Actually based on your error message, I suspect you are getting the error in the code calling the proc, and not in the proc itself.  What values are you trying to pass to the proc?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `CONVERT` with the wrong type. Pass `DATETIME` as parameter to `CONVERT` instead of `VARCHAR`

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,@dtAdjustedStartLY,120)
```

Comment: she needs to convert the dates to varchar so she can build a dynamic sql string.

Comment: @TabAlleman Then it doesn't make sense to use the last datetime style parameter to convert. It's only useful when converting strings to date

Comment: No, the style parameter also affects conversion of dates to strings.

Comment: @TabAlleman The question says: "Failure to convert the parameter value from String to Datetime." So, I assume he wants to convert strings to datetime.

Comment: I am just running the stored procedure in the ssrs dataset query designer, and its giving me an error there. When I see a pop up for the variables in the sp, I simply select blank for each variable and click OK. Then I get a msg box displaying "Failed to convert the parameter value from String to DateTime". I am not able to follow what is wrong in the code there??

Comment: Thanks @Oscar .I tried to do the way u told me to to pass datetime as parameter to convert instead of varchar but still the same error.

Comment: Thanks @TabAlleman.@Tab Alleman I am running the same in sql server mgmt studio, it is displaying the o/p perfectly. Only SSRS is going crazy over the convert function.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks. I tried your way of entering values instead of blanks and it worked, but now its breaking at one other parameter so trying to fix that. But thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This is an SSRS error.   You are trying to populate a DateTime parameter with a string that cannot be converted to a DateTime.

When you run the query in the ssrs dataset query designer, and get the pop-up for the parameters, input valid parameter values instead of blanks and try it.

Comment: Tab Thanks for your help. I appreciate it. I tried your way and it worked but now another parameter is breaking so trying to fix that. But thank you so much.